# Android Single Process Level Service

Tags: android

Here's the scenario:

I have a service that I want to start at device boot time.

The service will listen for multicast packets and send notifications to the user.

In order for the service to start running on system boot, I need to define a receiver listening for an intent contaning the following action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, which will then start the service.

If I have N number of applications, that all expect that service to be running, and I define the same receiver in all applications, I'm assuming N number of services will startup.

Is there any way to prevent multiple instances of the same service from running?

Comment: Why would a user have N number of your applications installed?

Comment: They can be different applications, but all require the same service to be running.

Comment: I get that but why would a user want to use *your* apps in particular?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. Let's just say our company provides useful data, and there are multiple apps that provide data in different ways, and therefore the need for multiple apps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not deliberately being difficult it's just that your question doesn't really explain what your apps do. You're effectively describing an application *suite* which means the answer would be to have a 'master' app which all others rely on. Have the 'master' app as the only one with the receiver and also hosts the service. Have the 'extra' apps check for the existence of the 'master', i.e., warn a user the 'master' must be installed for correct functionality. The 'extra' apps would be effectively 'plug-ins'.

Comment: We did think of this, but we want the apps and the service to be independent.  The apps don't require the service, but the service adds to the user experience.  For example, we are developing an android TV application that plays video.  When the video plays, we send out multicast packets with data describing the video that is playing.  The service we are discussing will run on a tablet/phone and listen to these packets.  It will send a notification to the user that "event X is playing, would you like to launch one of these 2nd screen applications to provide additional data?"

Comment: If we have multiple copies of the same service all listening to the same packets, the user will get N number of notifications for the same event playing on the TV.

Answer (score 0):

Android Services are actually singletons, meaning there will only ever be one instance running at any time.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/qv-z0HM5afo

According to the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29), every call to `startService()` will trigger the `onStartCommand()` event; however, new instances of the service will not be started if it is already running.

Comment: The problem is if each 'app' has the receiver and service code...`com.mycompany.app1.myservice` is not the same as `com.mycompany.app2.myservice`

Comment: @Stevebod - I see what you're going for in your discussion above.  In that case, you should really make it into a master/slave setup where only one app has the code for a service. From the OS perspective, those are completely different services, even with different class names.

Comment: @Stevebod - I know you don't want your apps to rely on another one, but having a single application that is "the service" is not unreasonable.

Comment: @derekerdmann We do understand the "master/slave" solution, but we're specifically interested in the possibility of having it be more transparent to the user.  It is a simple service, that we don't want the user to even be aware of when installing the apps.

Comment: We did throw around ideas where each service would query existing running services either via the PackageManager, or via broadcast intents, and potentially shut themselves down, or flip the enabled flag in the manifest. However, we always get into some situation where can't seem to work around.

Comment: @Stevebod : You mention broadcast intents in your comment above but have you tried `sendStickyBroadcast (Intent intent)`. I don't know if it would work between 'apps' but if the `Service` code has a nested receiver that's registered immediately in `onStartCommand` the result of `registerReceiver` will be the 'sticky' `Intent` or 'null'. If it's 'null' the `Service` could send a sticky broadcast allowing others to see it was the first to start. If not null then it would call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the os will kill your service if it is idle for too long. However, with some clever design you can handle this. Another thing is from a design perspective you should on run your service when necessry to be efficient in use.

Comment: @MisterSquonk My only concern with that approach is if the service is destroyed. Once the service is destroyed, I will need to send a broadcast intent out to have all the services attempt to start up and negotiate again.  Since there is already a sticky broadcast, none of them will start up.